# Merging and deleting duplicate items within a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries

```
[{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.1.1', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86400', 'lat': '32.05570', 'paramname': 'multiplicity', 'paramvalue': '4'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.1.2', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86400', 'lat': '32.05570', 'paramname': 'peak_current', 'paramvalue': '-11'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.1.3', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86400', 'lat': '32.05570', 'paramname': 'cloud_indicator', 'paramvalue': '0'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.1.4', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86400', 'lat': '32.05570', 'paramname': 'ellipse_major', 'paramvalue': '5.8'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.2.1', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86350', 'lat': '32.02770', 'paramname': 'multiplicity', 'paramvalue': '0'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.2.2', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86350', 'lat': '32.02770', 'paramname': 'peak_current', 'paramvalue': '-16'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.2.3', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86350', 'lat': '32.02770', 'paramname': 'cloud_indicator', 'paramvalue': '0'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.2.4', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86350', 'lat': '32.02770', 'paramname': 'ellipse_major', 'paramvalue': '1.6'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.3.1', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86730', 'lat': '32.07100', 'paramname': 'multiplicity', 'paramvalue': '0'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.3.2', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86730', 'lat': '32.07100', 'paramname': 'peak_current', 'paramvalue': '-35'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.3.3', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86730', 'lat': '32.07100', 'paramname': 'cloud_indicator', 'paramvalue': '0'}, {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.3.4'
```

which I want to group by the id subsection in the key `elementid`, in a way that appends the `paramname` and `paramvalue` values from dictionaries that have the `.2`, `.3` and `.4` to the "first" dictionary that has the `.1` ending, since every other item in the `.2`, `.3` and `.4` dictionaries are duplicates. When this would be done, I'd remove the `elementid` item and combine the `paramname` and `paramvalue` items.

So an example of my desired output in the end would then be

```
[{'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', 'lon': '59.86400', 'lat': '32.05570', 'multiplicity': '4', 'peak_current': '-11', 'cloud_indicator': '0', 'ellipse_major': '58'} ... ]
```

My code that creates the list of dictionaries from an XML file

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, ElementTree
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

file = urlopen('https://opendata.fmi.fi/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=getFeature&storedquery_id=fmi::observations::lightning::simple&timestep=1&starttime=2022-07-11T20:00:00Z&endtime=2022-07-11T20:05:00Z')
data = file.read()
tree = ElementTree(fromstring(data))
root = tree.getroot()

paramnames = []
paramvalues = []
lon = []
lat = []
obstime = []
ids = []

ET.register_namespace('wfs', "http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0")
ET.register_namespace('gml', "http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2")
ET.register_namespace('BsWfs', "http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0")
ET.register_namespace('xsi', "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance") 

for pn in root.findall('.//{http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0}ParameterName'):
    pnstr = (pn.text.replace('', ''))
    paramnames.append(pnstr)
for pv in root.findall('.//{http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0}ParameterValue'):
    pvstr = (pv.text.replace('', ''))
    paramvalues.append(pvstr)
for ps in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}pos'):
    psstr = (ps.text.replace('', ''))
    lons = psstr.split(None, 1)
    del lons[-1]
    lats = psstr.split(None, 2)
    del lats [-0]
    lon.append(lons[0])
    lat.append(lats[0])
for tm in root.findall('.//{http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0}Time'):
    tmstr = (tm.text.replace('Z', ''))
    obstime.append(tmstr)
for i in root.findall('.//{http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/wfs/2.0}BsWfsElement'):
    idstr = i.get("{http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2}id")
    ids.append(idstr)
zippedlist = list(zip(ids, obstime, lon, lat, paramnames, paramvalues)))
dictnames = ('elementid', 'obstime', 'lon', 'lat', 'paramname', 'paramvalue')
list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(dictnames,l)) for l in zippedlist]
print(list_of_dicts)
```

I tried sorting them by the `lon` item, but found out that it actually doesn't produce the result I wanted

```
list_of_dicts = sorted(list_of_dicts,
                    key = itemgetter('lon'))

for key, value in groupby(list_of_dicts,
                         key = itemgetter('lon')):
    for k in value:
        print(k)
print(list_of_dicts)
```

Output:

```
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.250.1', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:42', 'lon': '55.16820', 'lat': '30.88440', 'paramname': 'multiplicity', 'paramvalue': '1'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.250.2', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:42', 'lon': '55.16820', 'lat': '30.88440', 'paramname': 'peak_current', 'paramvalue': '21'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.250.3', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:42', 'lon': '55.16820', 'lat': '30.88440', 'paramname': 'cloud_indicator', 'paramvalue': '0'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.250.4', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:42', 'lon': '55.16820', 'lat': '30.88440', 'paramname': 'ellipse_major', 'paramvalue': '2.8'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.240.1', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:40', 'lon': '55.67710', 'lat': '31.12120', 'paramname': 'multiplicity', 'paramvalue': '1'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.240.2', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:40', 'lon': '55.67710', 'lat': '31.12120', 'paramname': 'peak_current', 'paramvalue': '109'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.240.3', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:40', 'lon': '55.67710', 'lat': '31.12120', 'paramname': 'cloud_indicator', 'paramvalue': '0'}
{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement.240.4', 'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:40', 'lon': '55.67710', 'lat': '31.12120', 'paramname': 'ellipse_major', 'paramvalue': '1.6'}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

combined_elements = defaultdict(dict)
for element in elements:
    # get values
    elementid = element['elementid'].rsplit('.',1)[0]
    paramname = element['paramname']
    paramvalue = element['paramvalue']
    # remove keys
    for key in ['elementid','paramname','paramvalue']:
        element.pop(key)
    # add to combined dict
    element.update({paramname:paramvalue})
    combined_elements[elementid].update(element)
    
# print elements
for elem in combined_elements.values():
    print(elem)
```

I used your first list as `elements`. The combined_elements still has the `elementid`s as keys (without the last `.x` part) so you can refer to them if you want.

Outputs:

```
{'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:42', 'lon': '55.16820', 'lat': '30.88440', 'multiplicity': '1', 'peak_current': '21', 'cloud_indicator': '0', 'ellipse_major': '2.8'}
{'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:02:40', 'lon': '55.67710', 'lat': '31.12120', 'multiplicity': '1', 'peak_current': '109', 'cloud_indicator': '0', 'ellipse_major': '1.6'}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's great and I'm accepting it as the solution. If I may ask; could this then be put back into a list without the`[dict_values([{'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05', ...` prefix with defaultdict?

Comment: just convert it to a normal `dict`: `dict(combined_elements)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
import json

tmp={}
for x in data:
    x['elementid']=re.sub(r'\.[0-9]+$', '', x['elementid'])
    idx = json.dumps({k: v for k,v in sorted(x.items()) if k not in ['paramname', 'paramvalue']})
    try:
        tmp[idx].append({x['paramname']: x['paramvalue']})
    except KeyError:
        tmp[idx]=[{x['paramname']: x['paramvalue']}]

ouput=[{**json.loads(k), **{k:v for x in list(tmp.values())[0] for k,v in x.items()}} for k,v in tmp.items()]
```

returns:

```
[{'elementid': 'BsWfsElement',
  'lat': '32.05570',
  'lon': '59.86400',
  'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05',
  'multiplicity': '4',
  'peak_current': '-11',
  'cloud_indicator': '0',
  'ellipse_major': '5.8'},
 {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement',
  'lat': '32.02770',
  'lon': '59.86350',
  'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05',
  'multiplicity': '4',
  'peak_current': '-11',
  'cloud_indicator': '0',
  'ellipse_major': '5.8'},
 {'elementid': 'BsWfsElement',
  'lat': '32.07100',
  'lon': '59.86730',
  'obstime': '2022-07-11T20:00:05',
  'multiplicity': '4',
  'peak_current': '-11',
  'cloud_indicator': '0',
  'ellipse_major': '5.8'}]
```

Comment: thanks for your work, didn't think of using json